# Can I delete/edit Models after they've been created through the GUI?

Tags: laravel-backpack

Typically I build up the models, then loop back and put the relationships in. It seems that I cannot do that in the GUI. I also cannot create a model without a migration, and then create the migration once I've 'fine-tuned' the model. Any advice? I also noticed that CRUDs is greyed out in the menu at the top. Is it possible I loaded something incorrectly?

-Regards

Comment: That is true - it is not currently possible to edit models once they're generated. We're considering different options to do so, but they all have downsides (editing files that the dev has modified is dangerous).

Comment: The greyed out menu options are planned features - I see how that could be confusing, we'll remove them ASAP.